# Auto populate data in same activity

Tags: java, android, autocomplete

I'm currrently creating an autocomplete name, and i want to auto populate all fields base on the selected name on the same activity and display it in edit text fields.

I tried to pass the value to the edit text it doesn't display the value.

Comment: How did you try? Post the code. So that anyone could help.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.